# Lightbox Overlay Position Absolute Not Working Correctly

Tags: css, lightbox, absolute

Hey Stackoverflow Community,

I have a simple lightbox script with a few images on the page, but it somehow doesn't work as it should. When I use `position:fixed` on then the overlay, then it is full and the image sticks to the top, but when I use `position:absolute`, then it is cut half way through page and the image is gone to the top.

There must be something really easy I am missing, right? Maybe my HTML structure is wrong?
The error can be found here live - http://kriskorn.eu/lightbox-error/

Thank you for all the help!
Kris

Comment: What are you trying to do with your absolute positioning instead of fixed?

Comment: can you please elaborate why p tag having padding top : 700px, check ".main p" class

Comment: @evan Yesterday I had another script and the position absolute was working correctly and that way I could also position my image to the center of the page from all sides. With fixed positioning, it doesn't work unfortunately.  
---
The 'p' tag has such a padding, so you could see why absolute positioning is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer I was looking for is, that you can't have `position:absolute` without some kind of JavaScript code. I used `position:fixed` after all, because that was already working for me.

Answer (score 0):

here are two issues

1) you are using `padding-top: 700px;` in `.main p` which force the images to go down the page . and with position absolute the images can never display with overlay. the overlay div will go up with scroll .here `position:fixed` can work .Reason is with position fixed the content will move upside and the overlay will stay on fixed position.

2) you should use `opacity:0.*` or any light color .you are using `0.95` which will not display the content below the div.

this should work please check

```
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
   /* display: none; */

}
```

with position absolute it will not cover all the page.
this is surprising. Why you are using this ??

```
.main p {
  padding-top: 700px;
```

}

this can also be an option.

```
.main p {
      padding-top: 10px;
   }
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* display: none; */
  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but that's not the problem. I already knew that fixed positioning works. Right now I am also looking at a Treehouse course - jQuery Basics and there the same code works with absolute positioning.

Comment: check second solution. that was not working due to padding-top: 700px; because with this your images are going down to window.

Comment: The `padding-top: 700px` is there to mimic a real life website. A real website would be a lot longer in height and therefore position absolute going back to the very beginning of the document is not okay. With fixed positioning the image doesn't go way up, but with that solution I can't center it on the page. I hope that clarifies the situation.